# Have iOS 9 project support iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, ios9

I built a project in XCode 7.1 and the project I made supports iOS9.

I need to make my project support iOS8. Things I've tried include..

Targets => [Project Name] => General => Deployment Info => Deployment Target => 8.0

Project => [Project Name] => Info => Deployment Target => iOS Deployment Target => 8.0

What settings do I need to change, or steps I need to take in order to support iOS8.

EDIT: Added erros

```
dyld: Symbol not found: ___NSArray0__
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/802183E4-6DCD-4809-AB46-C7CC50CE6FED/SLAmazonTurk.app/SLAmazonTurk
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
 in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/802183E4-6DCD-4809-AB46-C7CC50CE6FED/SLAmazonTurk.app/SLAmazonTurk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the device your testing on isn't updated to iOS9 if your application is set to launch targeted at iOS8.

If you are using the simulators I don't think it should be a problem as the simulators I believe automatically change to what your development target is. However, if you are trying to run on you own device that is below the development target of your project you will get an error.

**EDIT 1:** I may have misunderstood your question. What do you mean your *"the project you made supports iOS9"?*

**EDIT 2:**
*The platform line in your Podfile should be set to the lowest supported version. In otherwords use this:
platform :ios, '8.4'*

Comment: Ok, I have a project. Created in Xcode 7.1. It defaulted to setting the deployment target to 9.1. I tried setting the deployment target to 8.0. My physical device is on 8.3. It crashes on use on that device. On another physical device that's running 9.1 it runs just fine.

Comment: Ok thats much better, thank you! :) Whats the exact error you get in the console?

Comment: @KonradWright - why does it crash? Are you using APIs only available in iOS9?

Comment: @Adam I hope not. I added in the error log to the main question. Hope it helps

Comment: @user2876115 I added the error log to the question. Thanks!

Comment: I believe its something to do with your device. Other users have reported the same error. Like here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211894/xcode-7-beta-6-dyld-nsarray0-crash In terms of fixing it so that it works on your device I'm not sure. Have you tried setting the development target to 8.3?

Comment: @KonradWright Edited my answer, added another fix you could try :)

Comment: @KonradWright no worries buddy! have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

Targets => [Project Name] => General => Deployment Info => Deployment Target => 8.0

This is minimun target setting and

Project => [Project Name] => Info => Deployment Target => iOS Deployment Target => 8.0

This is maximum target setting.

So you can set the target settings to 8.0 and project settings to 9.1 .

Comment: Also, by reading the error, you could tell that my pods project was out of whack. Have to set the deployment target for that too. Nice concise answer. Add in the pod bit, and I'll make this "best"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but I removed CoreFoundation.framework and Add again with Status "Optional" and works on my iPhone with IOS 8.4 with XCODE 7.1 with deployment target => 8.0